# WP theme Genesis child - show featured image on home page?

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

Hoping someone out there who is familiar with Genesis hooks can give me a quick solution. I am not very familiar with PHP

In the child theme's functions file I have this:

```
/** Add the featured image section */
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'full_featured_image' );
function full_featured_image() {
if ( is_front_page() ) {
echo '<div id="full-image"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/home-header.jpg" /></div>';
}
}
```

I just want to change the front page image from the static one (images/home-header.jpg) to the featured image for the home page. What should I change in here?

Thanks in advance.

Kitka